# Change default location of Grails-plugins

Tags: grails, plugins

I'm helping out on a project and I came across the following problem.

All plugins are stored in a folder named .grails (development done in windows) and all the code is stored in GIT.

When a clone of the repository is performed, the plugins are missing since they are all stored in the .grails-folder that might not exist since it will only be created on the PC that actually ran the "grails install-plugin xxxx" command.

Is there a way to get the plugins to be stored in the repository?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Set grails.project.plugins.dir in BuildConfig.groovy to point to a directory (relative to project root) where you want the plugins to be stored. For example,

```
grails.project.plugins.dir="./plugins"
```

Then, rebuild your project.

I'm not sure why you need this though; when somebody tries to build or run your project on a machine without necessary plugins installed, Grails will install them automatically.

Comment: Cool! I'll give that one a go!

Comment: This is useful when you have a tag checked out locally separate from your trunk that uses different plugins or versions of plugins but the same version of Grails, and you want to run it without downgrading and downloading those same plugins that your trunk uses. It just provides a nice separation, which is why I'm doing this, because I keep switching between the two. It's not something I would commit, though, it is a local change only.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, but `.grails` is exists especially for that, for storing plugins outside project root.

When you call `grails run-app` on other machine - they will be downloaded automatically.

Comment: That was not the case, the console just told us that it could not find the plugins...

Comment: all plugins? or an one non-standard/self-made plugin?

Comment: I had the mail plugin, and spring security plugin, it started to complain about both of them if I remember it correctly

Comment: Hm, both are published to central repository. Does your other machine have internet access? or maybe it's behind a proxy?